# difference between window.onload=function_name and window.onload=function_name()

Tags: javascript

When I used window.onload=function_name() where function_name is a java script function, the function did not get executed. But it works fine when I use window.onload=function_name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.onload=function_name()` calls the function `function_name` and sets the `onload` handler to its return value.

`window.onload=function_name` sets the handler to the function itself, so `function_name` will be called when the `onload` event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload=function_name;
```

This will be executed as expected when windows loading finished, while this one:

```
window.onload=function_name();
```

Will be executed when browser reaches that point and the value for the function will be returned to the window.load after page loaded.